# Express Cert Troubleshooring

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, helmet.js

I've been having SSL issues with my site for the last year now, and I don't know where to even look for the cause.

When using my site API through postman, I get a generic "Could not get any response" error in postman.
If I go into setting and disable SSL verification, the error is gone and everything works.
Also, *Occasionally* mobile browsers will give a warning about the certificate that the user will have to bypass to get to the site. But usually, the sites cert info is fine and you get the green lock on the browser.
[image]

It's just a simple express server setup. I'm hoping someone can see the issue with my implementation.

```
const app = express();

//security suite middleware
app.use(helmet());

//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let routes = require('./routes');
app.use(routes);
let privateKey = fs.readFileSync('src/server/config/keys/privateKey.key');
let certificate = fs.readFileSync('src/server/config/keys/certificate.crt');
https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, app).listen(8081, () => console.log("Listening on port 8081!"));
```

Comment: Try add change the createServer to:

`https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

 res.writeHead(200);

 res.end("Welcome to Node.js HTTPS Servern");

}).listen(8443)`

Comment: My guess is that intermediate certificates are missing. Browsers try to work around this, often but not always successful. Other tools don't work around it. Check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for *chain issues*.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich, this is very helpful. The two errors I got were the certificate chain being incomplete, and "This server supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. Grade capped to B".  Do you know if that second error is important?

Comment: @SpeedOfRound: for your problem only the incomplete certificate chain is relevant.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I was able to fix my chain issue thanks to your info. If you want to put it down as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound: I just gave you the right hints. You can write your own detailed answer, which is not unusual.